How to debug a cucumber maven test case in eclipse?
How to debug a cucumber maven testcase having particular tag for example I need to debug a test case which is having tag as @smoke.
I tried debugging through debug configuration by passing goal as Dmaven.surefire.debug install
I'm getting unknown lifecycle phase "Dmaven.surefire.debug".

All environment options are provided with the -D flag. So you forgot the -. If you are on windows you have to separate the environment option from the flag with qoutes. So use -D"maven.surefire.debug"

The goal should still be "test". -D sets a Java System Property, as shown at https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html . You should really see if the "Debug as..." menu has options for "Maven test", after having set a breakpoint.
